# Does anyone have an example of Apache POI converting PPTX to PNG

Tags: java, apache, png, powerpoint, apache-poi

Does anyone know of a good example of converting a PPTX powerpoint presentation to some form of image? PNG/GIF/etc?

I can do it for a PPT but looking for a PPTX conversion example

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime it works (... copied it from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799972/ppt-to-png-convesion-with-apache-poi)):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

public class PptToPng {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("example.pptx");
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
        is.close();

        double zoom = 2; // magnify it by 2
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);

        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        XSLFSlide[] slide = ppt.getSlides();
        for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)Math.ceil(pgsize.width*zoom), (int)Math.ceil(pgsize.height*zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
            graphics.setTransform(at);

            graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
            slide[i].draw(graphics);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("slide-" + (i + 1) + ".png");
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this code work you gonna need the latest v5.* Apache POI snapshot.
http://poi.apache.org/download.html#nightly

Comment: The code works also for older POI versions (the original answer was from 2013), but of course I've changed so many details since then, so yes ... please a current version. You can find even more details in the [render page](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I subscribed to the development mailing list and asked this question.

The answer is that this functionailty is currently not supported by apache poi

Answer (score 1):

There's an example class `PPTX2PNG` now bundled with POI that seems to work with decent results for the PPTX decks I've thrown at it:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/util/PPTX2PNG.java

Answer (score 0):

pptx4j can help you to create SVG in HTML (though there is still work to do to support all shapes); and then you could use one of the tools which create a image from an automated browser window.