# Convert PPT file to Image in Android

Tags: android, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to convert a ppt file to some image format, so I can manipulate it in the Android Activity interface. As suggested in this question [PPT to PNG conversion with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799972/ppt-to-png-convesion-with-apache-poi) the Apache POI library does that for Java. 
I tried to use it on Android, however following the code of the above link it has dependency on classes from the java.awt package, that from what I searched can't be ported to Android ([How to add java.awt.image package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android)).

Can someone confirm this, if there is some way to use POI on android? Or maybe another alternative to achieve the same thing on Android?

Comment: i want to do the same. please post the solution if you solved it. what i am trying to do in my app is user will upload the .ppt file and i have to convert slides to images and save.

Comment: my android app was communicating with a server to get the ppt file, so at the end I made the conversion from ppt to images at the server side and just downloaded it in the android app.

Answer (score -2):

Use Apachi POI library and write this code in method where you want to convert

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("PPT file");
    SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(is);
    is.close();
    final Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    final Slide[] slide = ppt.getSlides();
    int i = 1;// Slide number
    String title = slide[i].getTitle();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) pgsize.getWidth(),
            (int) pgsize.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    Graphics2D graphics2d = new Graphics2D(canvas);
    // render
    slide[i].draw(graphics2d);
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream("Path to your file"));
```

Comment: Cannot work for android as `java.awt` package is not available there